# How do np.nan and None behave differently?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to know whether there is any difference between using np.nan and None while using pandas dataframe or numpy arrays. If there is, where exactly does this difference matter?

Comment: `np.nan` is a valid `float`, so can be an element of a `float` `dtype` `numpy` array.  `None` is a Python object, and can only be an element of an `object` `dtype` array.

Answer (score -1):

Np.nan means not a number and `None` can be applied in general to the other cases.
np.nan can be used as a bool for example:

```
if('Hello' == np.nan)
```

Comment: You can do `'hello' == None` too...

Comment: Generally `is None` is the recommended test.